# Facebook Connect - I always have to click logout before I can log in?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, authentication

As the title says, my project will never bring up the FB login screen until I have called

```
[facebook logout];
```

This makes sense when I've already logged in, but it happens on startup as well (i.e. the user is not yet logged in).

Hmmm...I've just tried resetting contents and settings in the simulator, and that seems to have fixed the problem. For my own peace of mind, why when I close the simulator and rerun the project does it not revert to either a state where the app is 'new' and hasn't been run before, or to a resume state - whereby the logged in user info would be available immediately?

On my device I have just tested this:

- Fresh install
- Open app, login via FB Connect
- Close app, remove from running in background apps
- Reopen app
- Try to login, no response until I first click logout

So is it somehow retaining the fact that it has logged in before? If so, is there a "loggedInAlready" variable or something similar that I can check against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
if([facebook isSessionValid])//if already able to log in
{
    [self loginToFacebook];//attempt to login automatically on startup
}
```

Seems to have solved the problem. I guess that because I had:

```
if([facebook isSessionValid]){
    [facebook login];
}
```

in the login button press, that when it resumed it was still in a valid session and so the button press wouldn't do anything until the logout button ended the session.
Now it automatically checks if the session is valid on startup, and if so it logs straight in for me.

:-) All's well that ends well.